# Apply CMP JTA on plain CDI (no EJB) is it possible in Java EE 6?

Tags: jpa, cdi, jta

Does anyone know if it's possible to make CMP JTA work on plain CDI beans? The goal is just to inject a DAO bean (which is NO EJB) into a JSF bean, annotate a method with some kick-ass annotation and make it work out of the box. Some thing like this :

```
@Named
public class ClusterController {

    @Inject
    private ClusterDAO clusterDAO;

    /**
     * A simple proxy method
     * @param cluster cluster to be saved to the DB
     */

    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createCluster(Cluster cluster) {
        clusterDAO.saveEntity(cluster);
    }
}
```

This `@Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)` does not do the trick (I'm using JBOSS EAP 6). I get :

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:692) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:562) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
```

Comment: CDI 1 doesn't manage transactions. This is handled by EJB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in plain Java EE 6 without some plumbing. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838221/jee7-do-ejb-and-cdi-beans-support-container-managed-transactions), by standard this is possible in Java EE 7 with JTA 1.2. You can get a quick picture about JTA 1.2 in [the Aquarium](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/jta_1_2_it_s).

So, a number of options remain:

- Write-your-own [transactional CDI Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172749/transaction-management-and-cdi) (maybe a duplicate to your question).
- Use [DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/) CDI extensions or [Seam transactions](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/transaction.html). This means using a non-standard framework, so portability may be harmed. If kick-ass is what you need, this might not be a real show-stopper for you.
- Upgrade to Java EE 7. However, [there is no EE7 EAP yet](https://community.jboss.org/thread/238566). If community WildFly is not the option.

IMHO, I'd stick with the standard and write/use an interceptor (if change of architecture/specification/vendor is really not the option). You can hopefully do an easy swap for JTA 1.2 transactions in case of a future migration.

You can find more detail in linked Q&As.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented CDI interceptor and it works like a charm. Sadly that there is no built-in solution in EE6.

Comment: EJB is a built-in solution. It's neat, efficient and standard. Don't shy away from it!